# Is there a conjectural analog of Ribet's theorem (Converse to Herbrand's Theorem) for Imaginary Quadratic fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

For $p$ a prime, let $Cl(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p))$ denote the class group of the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining a primitive $p$th root of unity. Associated to an eigenform of weight 2 and nebentype a power of the Teichmuller character which exhibits a congruence with an Eisenstein series is its mod $p$ Galois representation which is upper triangular. This Galois representation coincides with a line in an eigenspace in $Cl(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p))\otimes \mathbb{F_p}$.

It seems natural for anyone who is familiar with this construction of Ribet to ask if there are analogues of this result for for instance, **imaginary quadratic fields**? One can ascribe similar upper triangular Galois representations to class group data associated to these fields, can one have similar conjectural expectations in this case?

EDIT: Perhaps I should add a few details to make the analogy clearer. Let $Cl(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p))$ denote the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$ and $\mathcal{C}=Cl(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p))\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$, $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p[\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)/\mathbb{Q})]$-module and decomposes into eigenspaces. Choose a Galois stable line in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. a line in one of these eigenspaces. This will coincide with an extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$ inside the $p$ Hilbert class field which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. This in turn coincides with an upper triangular Galois representation $G_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Ribet showed that such Galois representations could be constructed out of congruences between eigen-cuspforms and Eisenstein Series. A little thought shows that for imaginary quadratic fields, class group data coincides with such upper triangular Galois representations too.